# Sequelize Migrate - Erro: TypeError: defineCall is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, migrations, sequelize-js

Ola estou fazendo uma API simples de campeonato, usei o `Sequelize` como ORM para meu banco de dados.

Criei a tabela Arbitro que tinha somente o campo NOME e não tinha o campo CPF na tabela.

Tive que incluir o campo CPF na tabela Arbitro e para fazer isso teria que usar  um migrate com Sequelize-CLI

Apos o `sequelize db:migrate` funcionar, para executar o projeto esta dando erro.

Mas ao executar meu projeto ocorre o erro abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui consta o codigo:
https://github.com/leonardocintra/campeonato-api

Procurei na net a causa do erro, mas sou novo de NodeJs e também cada caso era um caso.

Agradeço quem puder ajudar.
At.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você sobe seu projeto, no arquivo db.js ele carrega todas suas models e na linha 39 ele está tentando fazer o import de um arquivo que não é uma model "models/index.js".

```
    const dir = Path.join(__dirname, 'models'); // Nessa linha ele carrega todos arquivos que devem ser apenas suas models.
    Fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach((file) => {
        const modelDir = Path.join(dir, file);
        const model = sequelize.import(modelDir);
        db.models[model.name] = model;
    });
```

Tente remover esse arquivo "models/index.js" e rodar o projeto novamente, pois aparentemente ele não é necessário no projeto ou está no lugar errado.

Comment: Valeu Lucas! Deu certo... removi a pasta index.js ... ela foi criada pelo sequelize init e achei que tinha que manter ela